# PWM Communication without external hardware

Tags: pwm

I'm working on project related to [J1850](http://www.interfacebus.com/Automotive_SAE_J1850_Bus.html) bus. to my understanding, it's just a PWM communication, but circuits I found online include some extra hardware ([example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iiryzhkov/j1850_arduino/master/Tools/connection_to_arduino.png)).

[image]

What does circuit actually do? What's the reason I can't just hook bus to Arduino and read/write like regular PWM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keanu Reeves, nice to see **you** here! :D
The main reason is level-shifting of the logic signal, where that bus can have anything from 4V to 20V for its logic high level, while Arduino can have no more than 5V.
Also, the logic high output from Arduino is no more than 5V and it needs to be raised to the J1850 level (around 12V) to make sure it is high enough to be detected as a logic high, as well as to raise it above the electric noise usually present in a car.
The logic low on the bus is anything below 3.5V, while anything above 3V is considered a logic high by the Arduino, and anything between 1.5V and 3V is considered undefined or gray area (not recommended).

Another reason for that circuit is to protect the Arduino from the higher voltages on those bus/data lines.

Comment: if communication was guaranteed to be no more than 5v, could i avoid the circuitry and just connect D3 and D4 (from the example) directly to the bus?

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain a little more. Basically, you shouldn't avoid such circuitry because of the same voltage levels being interpreted differently by the J1850 bus and the Arduino. However, If the J1850 was also guaranteed to keep its logic low output below 1.5V, it should actually work in practice as far as the levels go. I'm not sure if there would be a problem with both the input and output pins of Arduino being connected directly to the bus.

Comment: I see. thank you